# how to use angular2 in mvc5 areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-template, asp.net-mvc-areas

i have a sample mvc5 project and i used my first angular 2 modules successfully on this project. now i want to create new  module inside my mvc areas. so i created new area with a  `.ts`file named `app.components` in my area solution! like what you see below:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'area-app',
    template:`<p>imanArea</p>`
}) 
export class areacomponent {<<bring below error!!!!!!!!!!!
    name = 'dd';
}
```

> experimental support for decorators is a feature
>   that is subject to change in a future release. set the
>   'experimentaldecorators' option to remove this warning

and second  is from my root project `rootproj/app/app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 ***below error for this line***
import { AreaAppComponent } from './Areas/SampleArea/app/app.areacomponent'

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Cannot find module'./Areas/SampleArea/app/app.areacomponent'

i checked my path and file names!! every thing is right but it doesn't find my path!

for more information i have to say all my essential angular files are in my root project and my `app.module` is inside a folder named **app**

means: rootProj/app/app.module and `rootProj/app/app.component.spec`

is it possible to use `angular2` and `mvc-Area` together in one project?? i didnt find any source about that.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use WebAPI to use Angular 2.

Back and Front-End are going to be in different project folders. And you will work with restful services.

[image]